# Field "item" does not exist using Spark MLlib pipeline for ALS

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I am training a recommender system with ALS (Spark version: 1.3.1). Now I want to use a `Pipeline` for model selection via cross-validation. As a first step, I tried to adapt [the example code](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-guide.html#example-pipeline) and came up with this:

```scala
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("ALS").setMaster("local")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
import sqlContext.implicits._

val ratings: RDD[org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.Rating] = // ...
val als = new ALS().setMaxIter(10).setRank(10).setRegParam(0.01)
val pipeline = new Pipeline().setStages(Array(als))
val model = pipeline.fit(ratings.toDF)
```

When I run it, the last line fails with an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Field "item" does not exist.
at org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(dataTypes.scala:1032)
at org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(dataTypes.scala:1032)
at scala.collection.MapLike$class.getOrElse(MapLike.scala:128)
at scala.collection.AbstractMap.getOrElse(Map.scala:58)
at org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType.apply(dataTypes.scala:1031)
at org.apache.spark.ml.recommendation.ALSParams$class.validateAndTransformSchema(ALS.scala:148)
at org.apache.spark.ml.recommendation.ALS.validateAndTransformSchema(ALS.scala:229)
at org.apache.spark.ml.recommendation.ALS.transformSchema(ALS.scala:304)
at org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline$$anonfun$transformSchema$4.apply(Pipeline.scala:142)
at org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline$$anonfun$transformSchema$4.apply(Pipeline.scala:142)
at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foldl(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:51)
at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foldLeft(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:60)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foldLeft(ArrayOps.scala:108)
at org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline.transformSchema(Pipeline.scala:142)
at org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineStage.transformSchema(Pipeline.scala:58)
at org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline.fit(Pipeline.scala:100)
at org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline.fit(Pipeline.scala:79)
at org.apache.spark.ml.Estimator.fit(Estimator.scala:44)
...
```

I do not use the string `"item"` anywhere in my code, so I assume it is a default of some kind. When I add `.setItemCol("itemId")` to `als` the exception message changes accordingly.

What is the meaning of `"item"`? How can I make the pipeline work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, the solution was actually quite simple: use `org.apache.spark.ml.recommendation.ALS.Rating` instead of `org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.Rating` and it will just work.

Otherwise `.setItemCol("product")` does the trick because `org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.Rating` has a field called "product" whereas `org.apache.spark.ml.recommendation.ALS.Rating` calls the corresponding field "item". There must be some magic going on that, given a string, accesses some field of a case class (reflection?).

Comment: IMHO, one should not map to a `org.apache.spark.ml.recommendation.ALS.Rating` class as you are doing double work. The [code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/recommendation/ALS.scala#L366) internally maps the `DataFrame` to a `Rating` RDD for you :). So you are going from Rating to Dataframe back to Rating. As you found out, tt seems that using `setUserCol` and `setItemCol` is the way of using the new Spark ML API.